# access logs on laravel sail

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

I'm trying out laravel sail for a local project and I can't for the life of me find an easy way to exec into the container and tail my logs. I'm sick of googling and finding nothing-- does anyone have a link to docs or know the easiest way to accomplish normal devving with Laravel sail? I'm considering giving up this technique and doing it the normal Docker way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sail is just a way to configure your docker environment easily, you can still run every docker command as normal, or even publish the sail files and modify them for yourself (and then remove the package). To enter a container execute `docker exec -it <container> bash` or `./vendor/bin/sail shell` or `./vendor/bin/sail root-shell`. To tail logs of a container, you can run `docker logs --follow <container>`.

Comment: And since `sail` will redirect everything that can't match to the docker CLI, we can do `sail logs -f <service-name>` and we'll get all live logs of a specific compose service.